# Azure B2C signIn policy - lack of functionality

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have a system where users are created in backoffice by admins(user with special role). Password reseting for users is also Admin's responsibility. This functionality is implemented using Graph API.

Users log in to their accounts using usernames(local account Id).

For this purposes I use B2C tenant with **"sign-in" policy** . The problem is that there is a password reset link => "Can’t access your account". By clicking on this link, users get Microsoft's out-of-the-box password reset process. I would like to delete this link to disable some extra actions, but I found no way for this.

**1. Is it possible to delete "Can’t access your account" link in B2C sign-in policy?**

B2C sign-in policy is not fully customizable. Microsoft site says that for the purposes of fully customize I need to use **"sign-up or sign-in policy"**. But looks like I can not use local account id in "sign-up or sign-in policy".

**2. Is it possible to use fully customizable UI without providing sign-up functionality to users? I mean is it possible to use sign-up or sign-in policy as a sign-in policy only with usernames(not emails)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `can` use a local account in sign-in-or-sign-up policy.

The fully customizable experience is within the `sign-in or sign-up` policy. 
Everything is thoroughly described in the docu here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization

There is even an excellent example here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization-helper-tool

using the `sign-in or sign-up` policy you can not only remove the password reset link. But can also disable password reset from the policy itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the basic Azure B2C I dont think you can control this,  Azure B2C are just rolling out the ability to create custom sign in journeys which will allow you to change everything, call extra rest APIs , implement alternative IDP's

In the last few days my UI has changed and they have just released documentation on custom journeys so that is a good place to start

As an alternative and i dont know its possible you could try using a custom UI theme on the Signin policy and then use javascript to hide the link